# How to test Dao objects with ScalaTest

Tags: scala, tdd, integration-testing, scalatest

I want to learn about best practices for testing dao objects. I have several dao objects interacting with db through anorm in a standalone scala application.

I want to write integration tests for these objects with ScalaTest. It should run tests on different database.

Comment: This sounds more like you want to do a repository test as opposed to a dao test, it that the case?

Comment: I want to be sure that dao methods work as expected if it's called repository test then yes. Maybe I use wrong terminology for it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this is standalone Scala app interacting with database, you can use ScalaMock.

As a native, open-source Scala mocking framework ScalaMock supports three different mocking styles:

1. Function mocks
2. Proxy (dynamic) mocks
3. Generated (type-safe) mocks

To use ScalaMock, mix `org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory` into your Suite class, as in:

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with ...
```

Comment: how it helps to test sql stuff are working as expected?

Comment: If you want to test that the SQL works correctly, you'll probably want to do an integration test with an instance of the database bootstrapped for the test.

Comment: You can create a trait, let's say DAO which will persist any object to some sort of  database, may be in-memory database. Since DAO is a trait, it is intended to be mixed into a class with a concrete implementation for a specific type of datastore.